# Catch wrong password

Tags: linux, shell, mysql

I have written a script that handles all of the steps for setting up a website on our server.  The problem I am running into is that, if someone enters the wrong MySQL password, the script keeps going and just skips creating a database.  I want it to stop if the password is incorrect, and ask for it again.

How can I handle this?

Here is my code -

```
read -s -p "Enter the MySQL password: " BASEPASS
mysql -u ${BASEUSER} -p${BASEPASS} <<CREATE_DB_QUERY
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS ${NEWDB};
CREATE USER ${NEWUSER} IDENTIFIED BY '${NEWPASS}';
GRANT ALL ON ${NEWDB}.* TO ${NEWUSER};
CREATE_DB_QUERY

mysqldump --opt --user=${BASEUSER} --password=${BASEPASS} ${BASEDB} > ${SQLFILE}
mysql --user=${BASEUSER} --password=${BASEPASS} ${NEWDB} < ${SQLFILE}
rm ${SQLFILE}
```

Comment: Can't you just let `mysql` prompt for the password itself (by removing the `read` altogether and giving the `-p` option without an argument)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure you `set -o errexit -o nounset` at the top of the script. Then loop through a simple check until you've got at least a valid password:

```
while true
do
    read -s -p "Enter the MySQL password: " BASEPASS
    mysql -u "$BASEUSER" "-p${BASEPASS}" 'SELECT 1' && break
done
```

Also, [Use More Quotes™](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes)!

Comment: And, thanks for the use more quotes comment/resource.  I am new to Shell, so am still figuring out this stuff.